# DataTable (like DataSet) component in Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, tdataset

I am a Delphi developer and a C# Developer. C# has the DataTable class that supports random access to Rows. Is there a third-party TDataSet (Delphi) component that is like DataTable (C#)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [`TClientDataSet`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TClientDataSet.html) class in Delphi, which functionality is similar to [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET.

Comment: Unfortunately `TClientDataSet` has a dependency on an external dll that will not already be on the client's machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TADODataSet`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADODataSet.html) for a disconnected in-memory dataset [as suggested by Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313233/937125). It is very powerful as opposed to `TClientDataSet` IMO.

But all the low level `ADO` stuff is not needed. it is simple as:

```
var 
   ds: TADODataSet;

ds := TADODataSet.Create(nil);

//add our fields
ds.FieldDefs.Add('InvoiceNumber', ftInteger);
ds.FieldDefs.Add('CustomerName',  ftWideString, 200);
ds.FieldDefs.Add('CreatedDate',   ftDateTime);
ds.FieldDefs.Add('Comments',      ftWideMemo);
ds.FieldDefs.Add('Quantity',      ftFloat);
ds.FieldDefs.Add('InvoiceTotal',  ftCurrency);
ds.CreateDataSet;

//Add a row of values - the easy way
ds.Append;
ds.FieldByName('InvoiceNumber').AsInteger := 1783;
ds.FieldByName('CustomerName').AsString   := 'Hubert Farnsworth';
ds.FieldByName('CreatedDate').AsDateTime  := Now;
ds.FieldByName('Comments').AsString       := 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
ds.FieldByName('Quantity').AsFloat        := 19809.32; //imperial gallons
ds.FieldByName('InvoiceTotal').AsCurrency := 99.95; //GBP
ds.Post;

//Add another row of values - with an array of values all at once
ds.AppendRecord([1784, 'Steven Gates', Now, '//no comment', 1292, 19.25]);
```

You can also edit existing data:

```
ds.First;
ds.Edit;
ds.FieldByName('InvoiceNumber').AsInteger := 1786;
```

You can then use [`TDataSource`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSource.html) to bind it to the `TADODataSet` and use data aware controls if needed linked to the `TDataSource`.

Answer (score 1):

[Data Storage Engine](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/data-access-engine.html#dats) in AnyDAC. In general, it is [ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) v 1, but for native code. It may be used together with TADMemTable.

PS: AnyDAC is a commercial product.

Answer (score 1):

kbmMemTable CodeGear Edition which you can download for free as part of kbmMW CodeGear Edition, after signing up at https://portal.components4developers.com (ignore cert. errors if any occur.. the site *is* valid).

kbmMemTable CodeGear Edition contains the most feature rich in memory table for Delphi.. for free.
It even contains:

- SQL support advanced high performance indexes filtering bookmarks
- dataset interchange with other dataset sources and destinations
- master/detail multiple cursors (and separate filters and indexes) to
- the physically same data very high performance versioning and
- tracking of datachanges including the ability to resolve those
- changes to someplace else via deltahandlers
- plus hundreds more features and goodies in the product

If you need source kbmMemTable Standard Edition is available, and if you need the best performance you can find in a Delphi memory dataset, you can get kbmMemTable Professional Edition as a bundled part of kbmMW Professional Edition and kbmMW Enterprise Edition.

best regards
Kim Madsen
www.components4developers.com

Answer (score 1):

JVCL has TjvMemoryData which supports random access to rows and fields. It is a bit more flexible than Delphi's own TClientDataSet.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent series from Cary Jensen comparing ClientDataSets and DataTables: [In-Memory DataSets: ClientDataSet and .NET DataTable Compared: Part 1 Overview](http://caryjensen.blogspot.de/2009/09/in-memory-datasets-clientdataset-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

A free (for personal use) in-memory database table is available from [AidAim](http://www.aidaim.com/in-memory_sql_database_delphi.htm)

> SQLMemTable is a fully functional in-memory database system; it
>   includes database, table, query and batch move components as well as
>   useful utility (with source code), demos and comprehensive help.
>   SQLMemTable does not require BDE or any external drivers and has small
>   footprint.

Another free (open source) component is [TxQuery](http://code.google.com/p/txquery/) (MPL)

> TxQuery component is a TDataSet descendant component that can be used
>   to query one or more TDataSet descendant components using SQL
>   statements

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to have a purely in-memory `TDataSet`. The issue with `TClientDataSet` (aside from the [bugs](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.datasnap/tclientdataset-createdataset-failing-wit/1097715)), is that you will take a dependancy on a DLL that customer won't have on their computer. (Meaning you have a ship a dll dongle).

Fortunately Microsoft already created a client-side, in-memory, native equivalent of a `DataTable`: the ADO `Recordset`.

You can make your ADO `Recordset`, give it fields, and then wrap it in a `TADODataSet` so it descends from the canonical Delphi `TDataSet` (or you can just use the ADO Recordset object directly).

```
var
    rs: Recordset;

//Use ADO Recordset to hold our in-memory table
rs := CoRecordset.Create;
rs.CursorLocation := adUseClient; //default is adUseServer
```

Now that you have the recordset, you define fields:

```
//add our fields
rs.Fields.Append('InvoiceNumber', adInteger,      0,   adFldUpdatable, EmptyParam);
rs.Fields.Append('CustomerName',  adVarWChar,     200, adFldUpdatable, EmptyParam);
rs.Fields.Append('CreatedDate',   adDBTimeStamp,  0,   adFldUpdatable, EmptyParam);
rs.Fields.Append('Comments',      adLongVarWChar, -1,  adFldUpdatable, EmptyParam);
rs.Fields.Append('Quantity',      adDouble,       0,   adFldUpdatable, EmptyParam);
rs.Fields.Append('InvoiceTotal',  adCurrency,     0,   adFldUpdatable, EmptyParam);
```

You also have to `Open` the recordset to materialize the fields:

```
var
   o: OleVariant;

//It's impossible in Delphi to omit parameters. So we do it the late-binding IDispatch way
//  rs.Open(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
o := (rs as IDispatch);
o.Open;
```

You have your empty in-memory table. Now you can add data rows:

```
//Add a row of values - the easy way
rs.AddNew(EmptyParam, EmptyParam); //moves cursor to newly added row
rs.Fields['InvoiceNumber'].Value := 1783;
rs.Fields['CustomerName'].Value  := 'Hubert Farnsworth';
rs.Fields['CreatedDate'].Value   := Now;
rs.Fields['Comments'].Value      := 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
rs.Fields['Quantity'].Value      := 19809.32; //imperial gallons
rs.Fields['InvoiceTotal'].Value  := 99.95; //GBP

//Add another row of values - you can add by single value
rs.AddNew('InvoiceNumber', 1784);

//Add another row of values - you can add by field names
rs.AddNew(VarArrayOf(['InvoiceNumber', 'InvoiceTotal']), VarArrayOf([1784, 22.37]));

//Add another row of values - you can add by ordinal index
rs.AddNew(VarArrayOf([0, 2]), VarArrayOf([1785, Now]));

//Move to the start of the Recordset, so it will be ready for the person using it.
if (not rs.BOF) or (not rs.EOF) then //You can't MoveFirst on a Recordset if the Recordset is empty. (It's throws an error instead of not throwing an error)
rs.MoveFirst;
```

And finally, we want a familiar `TDataSet` wrapper around it:

```
var
   dataset: TDataSet;      

//Wrap the recordset is a TDataSet descendant 
//that knows how to talk to an ADO recordset: the TADODataSet.
dataset := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
dataset.Recordset := rs;
```

So i can test it:

```
var 
   ds: TDataSet;
begin
   ds := CreateMemoryDataSet();
   ShowMessage(DataSetToMarkdown(ds));
```

and i get the expected in-memory data:

```
| InvoiceNumber | CustomerName      | CreatedDate          | Comments | Quantity | InvoiceTotal |
|---------------|-------------------|----------------------|----------|----------|--------------|
| 1783          | Hubert Farnsworth | 7/25/2017 3:32:21 PM | The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog | 19809.32 | 99.95 |
| 1784          |                   |                      |          |          |              |
| 1784          |                   |                      |          |          | 22.37        |
| 1785          |                   | 7/25/2017 3:32:22 PM |          |          |              |
```

You can also modify the in-memory values:

```
ds := CreateMemoryDataSet();    
ds.First;
ds.Edit;
ds.FieldByName('InvoiceNumber').AsInteger := 1786;
ShowMessage(DataSetToMarkdown(ds));

| InvoiceNumber | CustomerName      | CreatedDate          | Comments | Quantity | InvoiceTotal |
|---------------|-------------------|----------------------|----------|----------|--------------|
| 1786          | Hubert Farnsworth | 7/25/2017 3:32:21 PM | The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog | 19809.32 | 99.95 |
| 1784          |                   |                      |          |          |              |
| 1784          |                   |                      |          |          | 22.37        |
| 1785          |                   | 7/25/2017 3:32:22 PM |          |          |              |
```

Comment: I gave you a +1 for suggesting ADO and mentioning `TClientDataSet` bugs, but you really do not need all that low level ADO stuff. See my answer...

Comment: @kobik Thank you for that. That's exactly what i was hoping would happen - someone take my answer and run with it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in **TECDataset** (EverClassy Dataset) from **Inovativa** (http://www.inovativa.com.br/public), which is an in-memory dataset that can be populated with objects of any class.